# Computing values of feature importances

Tags: scikit-learn

Where does [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/) compute the values of `sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.feature_importances_`?

Comment: I guess you read https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html

Comment: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/b194674c4/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py#L415

Comment: May you briefly elaborate on the background of your question, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corresponding code should be within https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py but I do not find `sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.feature_importances` there, however there is a class called `RandomForestClassifier`.

Answer (score 0):

The relevant section of the source code is here: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/b194674c4/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py#L415